# Python reportlab pyRXP on OS X

Tags: python, reportlab

So I am trying to install pyRXP on my os x machine (using anaconda).
If I use pip, import pyRXP doesn't work,
I have also tried to install by cloning https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/pyrxp 
and running the setup.py file
It claims I need to compile something if I am not on windows, but I can't work out what, where that source is. 
Sorry I am kind of new to python, and this has become very confusing, no amount of googling is helping. 
Cheers for any help.

Comment: can we have the stack trace of the error

Comment: and do you have xcode (commandline tools) installed?

Comment: I have xcode installed, and reportlab installed, and working. How do I do a stack trace in python? Its just a module not found thing:
>>> import pyRXP
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyRXP

Comment: I am installing to the correct place, any other module works fine. which pip = ~/anaconda/bin/pip, which python = ~/anaconda/bin/python

Comment: `sudo pip install pyrxp` works for me on osx. what is going wrong with you?

Comment: when I use that, I get "ImportError: No module named pyRXP"

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of pyRXP, the module seems to have been renamed to pyRXPU. Something about supporting Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `pyRXP` (which supported 8 bit characters) has been removed and only `pyRXPU` (supporting 16 bit unicode characters) is in the package now, although the [documentation](http://pyrxp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) still suggests you can `import pyRXP`! I've submitted an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/pyrxp/issues/1/cannot-import-pyrxp-from-pip-installed) about this.

The only solution, if using the latest version of pyRXP (as suggested by the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29284188/1862861) answer), is to instead do:

`import pyRXPU`

*Update*: The [documentation](http://pyrxp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html), and README file in the [repository](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/pyrxp), have now been [fixed](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/pyrxp/pull-requests/1/updated-readme-documentation-and-test/) to only reference `import pyRXPU` and no longer use `import pyRXP`.